# Sencha Touch 2 Model how to validate a model where two fields have to have the same value?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Working with Sencha Touch 2 model validation.

I have an email field and a email confirmation field.

The user has to enter his email address inside both fields, and they both have to match.

How can I check that using the model validation?

Basically I will need a custom validation rule.

```
 Ext.define('TestApp.model.RegisterModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [
                { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'confirmedEmail', type: 'string' }
            ],
            validations: [
                { field:'firstName', type:'presence', message: 'first name error' },
                { field:'lastName', type:'presence', message: 'last name error' },
                { field:'email', type:'email', message: 'email error' }
                { field:'confirmedEmail', ????? }
                // is there a custom function to make sure the email value is the same as the email confirmed value?
            ]
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use listeners and validate ur fields. Below code snippet

```
if (regForm.findField('emailid').getValue() != regForm
                .findField('conformemailid').getValue()){

            msg = "Email id not matches";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to define a [custom validation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Validations). It is relatively easy.